# Deleting NamedTemporaryFile in Python after a subprocess call

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I don't want to delete the temp file until the subprocess execution completes and hence, I invoke the subprocess script as:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess


def main():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", delete=False) as temp:
        temp.write("Hello World")
        temp.flush()

        print(f"Temp file is: {temp.name}")
        args = ["python3",
                os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/hello_world.py",
                "--temp-file", temp.name]
        subprocess.Popen(args)
    return


main()
```

hello_world.py

```
import argparse
import sys


def print_hello():
    print("Hello World")
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="""Test case""")

    parser.add_argument('--temp-file',
                        required=True,
                        help='For test')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    print_hello()
    sys.exit(0)
```

I was hoping the temp file to be deleted once subprocess execution finishes.

Do I need to manually delete the temp file in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `subprocess.Popen()` starts the process but does not wait for it to finish.

If you want to wait for the process to finish before exiting the `with` block, you can use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead.

**Edit:** Per your comment, you don't want to wait for the process to finish. Since you are creating the file with `delete=False`, it won't be deleted when the file pointer is closed at the end of the `with` block, so you will need to manually delete the path, either in the parent or child process.

Comment: I actually dont want to wait for the subprocess to finish